# Как получить массив координат между двумя точками?

Tags: google-maps-api, яндекс-карты, gps

Есть ли способ получить через API (Яндекс.Карты,Google Maps) массив координат между двумя заданными точками?   Или может есть методик расчёта? Координаты нужны лежащими на прямой между двумя точками, просчитывать проезд нет необходимости.

Answer (score 2):

Ну все координаты получить нельзя (их просто бесконечное количество), а вот пройти дугу большого круга с каким-то шагом - можно

Вот, например, [interpolate](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/geometry) из `google.maps.geometry.encoding namespace`

```
interpolate(from, to, fraction)
Parameters: 
from:  LatLng
to:  LatLng
fraction:  number
```

Под капотом, вероятно, используется [SLERP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp). Если понадобится самостоятельно реализовывать - Intermediate point  [тут](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

An intermediate point at any fraction along the great circle path between two points can also be calculated

```
Formula:
a = sin((1−f)⋅δ) / sin δ
b = sin(f⋅δ) / sin δ
x = a ⋅ cos φ1 ⋅ cos λ1 + b ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ cos λ2
y = a ⋅ cos φ1 ⋅ sin λ1 + b ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ sin λ2
z = a ⋅ sin φ1 + b ⋅ sin φ2
φi = atan2(z, √x² + y²)
λi = atan2(y, x)
where   f is fraction along great circle route 
(f=0 is point 1, f=1 is point 2), 
δ is the angular distance d/R between the two points.
```

Comment: @Madushko Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом)

Answer (score 0):

Присоединяюсь к ответу выше, также пример простой реализации можно посмотреть тут https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/polyline_animation в функции generateSmoothCoords